# Python gui format json

Tags: python, json, user-interface

I'm trying to show a json in my gui but right now it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to be properly formated. I've tried using this :

```
json_text = StringVar()
json_formatted = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
json_text.set(json_formatted)
```

It worked when I printed it but not in my gui
I've also tried using:

```
test_json_text = Label(o_canvas_l, anchor='w', textvariable=json_text)
test_json_text.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: The text is centered. You have to set left-aligned text for the GUI element that displays it.

Comment: @kol I've tried (I edited the question) but for some reason it didn't wok

Comment: For multiline text the `Message` widget is better than `Label`. Set `anchor="w"` to make the text left-aligned. Unfortunately, it wraps long lines. The `Text` widget also works, and its text wrapping can be turned off. I would use something like `text = tk.Text(frame, wrap=tk.NONE)
text.insert(tk.END, "before\nhello, world lorem ipsum\nafter")
text.configure(state="disabled")
text.pack()`

Comment: @kol Thanks it worked, if you put it as answer I can mark it as the correct sollution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiline text the `Message` widget is better than `Label`. Set `anchor="w"` to make the text left-aligned. Unfortunately, it wraps long lines. The `Text` widget also works, it's left-aligned by default, and its text wrapping can be turned off. I would use something like:

```py
text = tk.Text(frame, wrap=tk.NONE)
text.insert(tk.END, "before\nhello, world lorem ipsum\nafter")
text.configure(state="disabled")
text.pack()
```